# How to differentiate endevent of music and channel?

Tags: python, events, audio, pygame

In pygame I can use pygame.mixer.music to load and play long audio files (by streaming), or pygame.mixer.Sound & pygame.mixer.Channel for shorter ones (that are loaded entirely into memory) - as I understand correctly.

I'd like to use both of these methods. However I'd also like to know, when playback of given Channel or Music has just finished. There are methods for that: `set_endevent()` - on both music and channel. When I use `pygame.locals.USEREVENT` as a type of event, when channel's playback is finished i receive event with `code == <channel_id>`. When music's playback is finished, `code` is always 0. Thus I cannot tell the difference, whether it is music that stopped, or channel with id 0.

Is there any way to tell them apart?

Answer (score 0):

-.- I misunderstood the documentation. There is said:

> The type argument will be the event id sent to the queue. This can be any valid event type, but a good choice would be a value between pygame.locals.USEREVENT and pygame.locals.NUMEVENTS. If no type argument is given then the Channel will stop sending endevents.

And I understood I should choose either `USEREVENT` or `NUMEVENTS`. I was constantly looking for a way to use some new event types but I thought it is impossible. So I chose `USEREVENT`, hoping that no other pygame module uses it, and thinking it's better than `NUMEVENTS`.

But then I came up with idea, that maybe these types are just numbers and "between" means *literally* between. So after I checked it appeared that `USEREVENT == 24` and `NUMEVENTS == 32`. So I can basically use any number from 25 to 32...

Silly me. :)

Only one thing remain: let's take that I used 25 as type for `Channel.set_endevent()`. How to get my channel id now?

---

**Edit:**

Ok, now I have a full image. It's even better - I think. If I understand correctly: `pygame.USEREVENT` (equal 24) is the *first* of many events up to `pygame.NUMEVENT` (equal 32). Any of them have an attribute `code` that can be used for whatever I want (and Channel uses it to put its id). So basically I can use `pygame.USEREVENT + 0` for channels and `pygame.USEREVENT + 1` for music.

Correct me please if I'm wrong.